# Merging {newcommand} into {macros}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

At the moment, there are 90 question tagged as [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros), i.e. dealing with matters of "macro programming" (as in section R of the UK TeX FAQ). The site also features 37 questions tagged as [newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newcommand), covering the do's and dont's of creating new commands (and modifying existing ones). But wait ... this is macro programming, isn't it?

Having tried to come up with a sensible distinction between the two "tag areas", I do believe there is none. The [newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newcommand) tag probably was created because `\newcommand` is the first thing a nascent macro programmer will encounter, although [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros) is the general term. In accordance with that, the "harder" programming questions (the ones that e.g. Joseph Wright and Will Robertson excel in answering) tend to be tagged with [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros). (That *is* a distinction, but not a sensible one -- we don't feature tags like [tikz-pgf-easy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf-easy) and [tikz-pgf-hard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf-hard).)

I suggest to define [newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newcommand) as a tag synonym for [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros), i.e to merge [newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newcommand) into [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros).

EDIT: I created a [tag synonym suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/macros/synonyms).

EDIT 2: As an amendment, I propose to define [commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commands) as a tag synonym for [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros). Please consider [voting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having enough votes in the question and the proposed synonym too, I've taken the liberty to approve this synonym.

Comment: Fine! So I merged synonym and master tag.

Answer (score 1):

[newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newcommand) marks questions about defining macros with LaTeX, meaning also certain restrictions.
In contrast, [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros) is about creating and using TeX's macros in general. So, perhaps this could remain distinguished.

But I admit that I thought the same when looking at the [newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newcommand) tag, also because I prefer descriptive tags over command name tags.

Comment: While I see what you mean, I think lockstep is correct here: the distinction is quite diffuse, and do we really need a tag for `\newcommand`?

Comment: For me it's also fine to merge. Mainly, I expressed thoughts also to support a discussion. I suggest, create and vote for a synonym, using the site's community features. If the synonym is established because of sufficient votes, I'll be glad to merge then.

Comment: I created a tag synonym suggestion. (And as the creator, I'm not allowed to vote for it.)

Comment: As you retagged the question to {status-completed}, do you intend to merge also {commands} into {macros} (see EDIT 2), or should this be a separate question?

Comment: @lockstep: I will approve and merge the two tags, also because of the voting on [this earlier question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404/which-expression-is-more-common-and-defining-for-latex-commands-command-or-macr). At least, all {commands} tagged questions refer to {macros}, not to primitive control sequences, which at some time may have their own tag.